# decrease speed in upward textview animation (swift3)

Tags: ios, animation, swift3, textview, uitextview

My code below scrolls the textview to the top. How can I make the animation half of its current speed. theTextView is the textview i am using.

```
      theTextView.contentOffset = .zero
    theTextView.setContentOffset(.zero, animated: true)
```

Comment: Are you using both lines? You should only be using
 `theTextView.setContentOffset(.zero, animated: true)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about a simple UIViewAnimation without using the included .setContentOffset method of UiTextView. Could be something like this:

```
var speed: CGFloat = 0.3 // speed in seconds

UIView.animate(withDuration: speed, animations: {

theTextView.contentOffset = .zero

}, completion: nil)
```

You can change the animation speed by changing the speed variable.

Comment: How can i get it to move to the bottom whats the opposite of .zero?